# mysql installation with datadir home directory of user giving permission denied error 13

Tags: mysql

I am trying to initialize the mysql and datadir=/home/user/mysqldata
but it is througing the error permission denied

````
root@localhost mysql]# bin/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/home/user/mysql-data
2021-11-23T17:35:24.562009Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2021-11-23T17:35:24.562124Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.27) initializing of server in progress as process 56149
2021-11-23T17:35:24.564873Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/home/user/mysql-data/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2021-11-23T17:35:24.564881Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /home/user/mysql-data/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
2021-11-23T17:35:24.564978Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-11-23T17:35:24.565137Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql-8.0.27-linux-glibc2.12-x86_64/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.27)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.```


I create a folder /home/user/mysql-data and changed the ownership to mysql and changed the mode also to 750/777 also.
Also disabled selinux, Os is centos 6.9
````

Comment: The database normally runs under user `mysql`. Does this user have right in  your `/home/users/mysql-data` directory ?

Comment: users is having 700

Comment: @srimannarayana Please [edit] your question to include the output of `stat /home/`, `stat /home/user/`, `stat /home/user/mysql-data` and `groups mysql`.

Comment: After chaning the main user directory to 750 mode the initialization is completed . But for the data directory i given chmod -R 750 /home/users/mysql-data it is not worked, when i given chmod -R 750 /home/users then it worked

Comment: @srimannarayana Keep in mind that the user has "to get there". This will not be possible if one directory on the way has not the proper permissions.

Comment: @Progman but -R is given while extending ,thank u

Comment: @srimannarayana The argument `-R` is recursive for the target directory content, not for the path segments to the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, you can start/stop the `mysqld` daemon in System Settings:

1. Open System Settings
2. Scroll to the bottom, and select the MySQL option
3. Under Instances tab, click 'Start MySQL Server'

This worked for me, and I hope it works for you!